# Magento top and side navigation

Tags: magento, content-management-system, navigation

In the top navigation bar I would like Home, Contact Us, Warranty etc.

In the side navigation bar I would like only my product Categories and sub-categories.

Magento has a default set up of whatever I put into CMS static blocks or Admin->Product Categories automatically goes in both the side and top navigation.

My question is How do I get the top navigation to only read my CMS Static Blocks and my side navigation to only contain my product and product categories (aka. what I put into Admin->Product Categories)